# Make python3 venv permanent after ssh termina close

Tags: python, python-venv

Few year ago I created a proxy script with python and Flask. It only run up app and bypass a request to the direction and added "response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'" to avoid CORS calls between server.

When I installed ubuntu 18.04, the only way to install python environment with "flask" and "request" libraries was to create a "venv" environment. I can't install directly in ubuntu with pip. So, I did it and I create my virtual environment for flask.

My problem is after all already succesfull, I run venv "source venv/bin/activate" and then launch my scrpipt "python3 server.py". Everything went well, but when I close the ssh connection "venv" is down also. I tried run with with "python3 server.py &" but the same.

How can I make "venv" virtual environment permanent, not to go down after exit the ssh connection?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I was installing everything for python2. I installed sudo apt install python3-pip, and then install all needed libraries with python3 and I could run up without venv environment